# Do piśācas' (ghosts) exist in temples or in our homes?

Tags: temple, mantras, ghosts

I was once said by an elderly man that we should not touch the backside of a temple while doing pradakshina because ghosts and rakshasas live there and touching that part will wake them. Supporting this claim we also  have a shloka/mantra.

> उत्तिष्ठन्तु  भूतपिशाचा येते भूमि भारका |
>   येतेष्टामविरोधेन ब्रह्म कर्म समारभे ||
>
> uttiṣṭaṃtu bhūtapiśācā yete bhūmi bhārakā |
>   yeteṣṭāmavirodhena brahma karma samārabhe ||

Which randomly means asking the ghosts, rakshasas to vacate the place as we are starting a brahma karma(auspicious deed).

The above mantra is chanted before starting any pooja.

- Do ghosts and rakshasas live behind the deity in the temple?
- Do they live in our homes?

[image]

What is the meaning of this picture?

<sup>Picture taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_temple_architecture#Dravidian_architecture_) wikipedia page</sup>.

Comment: Well who knows, ghosts could be anywhere. People with strong subtle vision can see them.

Comment: There is also a shloka in puja vidhi asking about departure of Rakshasa (Bad elements , impure things or thoughts) and coming of Gods, , which is similar, although it's not related to question but similar.-आगमार्थं तु देवानां गमनार्थं तु रक्षसाम् ।
देवतापूजनार्थाय घण्टानादं करोम्यहम् ॥

Comment: @SwiftPushkar That's the Ghanta Puja mantra..when we first ring the bell during Puja its usually recited alongwith..

Comment: @Rickross - Yes :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ghosts may reside in houses/homes which lack spiritual or general purity, peity, and devotion to the god.

Quoting from the Garuḍa Mahā-Purāṇa .

> [Chapter 22](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/page/n849/mode/1up?view=theater), Preta Khaṇḍa (Dharma-kāṇḍa) of the Garuḍa Mahā-Purāṇa
>
> The Lord of the Ghosts said -
>
> 57. **We reside and enjoy in a house where there is no purity** and where people do not observe truthfulness and restraint and where outcastes,
>     robbers, etc. join together and take meals.
> 58. **We take delight in haunting the house where no mantras are recited**, where no oblation is offered, where no homa is performed and
>     where people do not read the Vedas? regularly nor perform religious
>     rites.
> 59. **We hover around the house where gods are not honored**, where the householder is a vile wretch, without shame and decency, and where the
>     poor husband is controlled by his sturdy wife.
> 60. We enjoy gaiety in the house where covetousness, fury, somnolence, sorrow, fear, haughtiness, lethargy, quarrels, and deception reign
>     supreme.

So basically, any house or place that lacks spirituality, devotion and peity forms a conducive ground to be haunted by ghosts.

Regarding temples, we cannot be sure, but if we go by the above mentioned logic, then the abandoned/desecrated temples with no presiding priests might be haunted by ghosts since those places don't have purity and regular chanting of mantras.

Comment: I hope this answer reaches more people.

Comment: Good answer but I think you forgot to answer the last part of the question.

Comment: @ShriRambhakt yes, that's done deliberately by me. because the sources on that topic are obscure, and also I got lazy trying to compile all of it into an answer. maybe in next few days I'll try, when I regain that kind of energy. Lol. ;)